# APS.NET CORE 5 Web Api - Static files, Authorization and Authentication

Tags: authentication, authorization, asp.net-core-webapi

I have static files folder:

[image]

And I followed Microsoft documentation to validate authorization and authentication:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Everything is ok, but all my request are returning 401, includes SignIng request.
My StartUp file:

[image]

[image]

My controller does not have [Authorize].

[image]

I need to Sign in to receive token, to show files only for authenticated users.
I have JWT authentication btw.

What I'm doing wrong? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could find the explain in official document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0

In the preceding code, the fallback authorization policy requires all users to be authenticated. Endpoints such as controllers, Razor Pages, etc that specify their own authorization requirements don't use the fallback authorization policy. For example, Razor Pages, controllers, or action methods with [AllowAnonymous] or [Authorize(PolicyName="MyPolicy")]
RequireAuthenticatedUser adds DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement to the current instance, which enforces that the current user is authenticated.

And I tested with the codes,we could see the result:
[image: testresult]

And the document also provide an alternative approach to serve files based on authorization is to:
Store them outside of wwwroot and any directory accessible to the Static File Middleware.
Serve them via an action method to which authorization is applied and return a FileResult object:

```
[Authorize]
public IActionResult BannerImage()
{
    var filePath = Path.Combine(
        _env.ContentRootPath, "MyStaticFiles", "images", "red-rose.jpg");

    return PhysicalFile(filePath, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Comment: thx, I have missed [AllowAnonymous]. So, If I use options.FallbackPolicy I don't need [Authorze] in all my controllers?

Comment: Yes，if you don't want add the [Authorze] Attribute every where in your controller,you could also try FallbackPolicy